# AFOAuth2Client equivalent in Java

Tags: java, android, rest, oauth

I need to authorize against an oauth provider with a username and password.  On the iOS side there's the open source library 'AFOAuth2Client' that works well.  Is there a library?  Or how would I do in Java code?  I've tried this:

```
this.http_client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    oauth_consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.clientId, Constants.clientSecret);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://test.com/v1/oauth/token?api_key=gnxkfzquuahaswuxjrkv9ct3");
    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> name_value_pairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(2);
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("grant_type", "password");

    params.put("username", "xxxxx@everything.com");
    params.put("password", "xxxxx");
    Iterator iter = params.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
        name_value_pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair((String) pairs.getKey(), (String) pairs.getValue()));
    }

    try
    {
        // Put our parameters in our Post
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(name_value_pairs));

        // sign our request
        this.oauth_consumer.sign(httppost);
        // Yoiks, and away!
        HttpResponse response = http_client.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null)
        {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(instream, writer);
            String theString = writer.toString();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(theString);
            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
            instream.close();
            return json;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks, Graeme

Answer (score 2):

I ended up here because I had the same problem. I ended up doing the following:

Found out what exactly is that the user expects from the application. In my case, it´s the following (and I figure it´s yours too since you are using the AFOAuth2Client library.

A GET request with the following parameters: `"URL_TO_YOUR_SERVER"?client_id=YOURCLIENTID&client_secret=YOURCLIENTESECRET&username=YOURUSERNAME&password=YOURPASSWORD&grant_type=password`

Yes, the value for "grant_type" is password in case of log in (which means you will receive your auth token as well as your refresh token). Whatever the response may be, you need to find out first. In my case it was data sent back in JSON format. I´ll post the code that ensued to get this done:

The following method simply constructs the url with the GET parameters I mentioned.

```
private String getSignInURL(UserAccount accountValues){
    List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", accountValues.getClient_id() ));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret",accountValues.getClient_secret() ));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", accountValues.getEmail() ));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", accountValues.getPassword() ));

    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

    return this.baseUrl+"?"+paramString;
}
```

The following method makes the GET call.

```
public AuthTokens userSignIn(UserAccount accountValues)
        throws Exception {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(this.getSignInURL(accountValues));

    AuthTokens authTokens = null; 

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            reportException(response);
        } 

        authTokens = getAuthTokensFromJson( getJsonFormat(response.getEntity().getContent()) ); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

  return authTokens;
}
```

The following makes the String that allows you to create a JSON Object `response.getEntity().getContent()`

```
protected String getJsonFormat(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

And last, here is the method that reads the authTokens form the server response.

```
private AuthTokens getAuthTokensFromJson(String toJson) throws IOException, JSONException {
    AuthTokens authTokens = new AuthTokens();

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(toJson);
    authTokens.setAuthToken(jObject.getString("access_token"));
    authTokens.setRefreshToken(jObject.getString("refresh_token"));

    return authTokens;
}
```

That would be all, hope it helps some.

Comment: I used this method, but had to switch to `HttpPost` instead of `HttpGet`. Thanks for the example, Joy.

Comment: I am so glad I could help :)